# При верном вводе данных в форму выдает ошибку что не найден пользователь

Tags: php

Когда регистрируюсь все ок данные переходят на базу, а при авторизации выдает ошибку.

```
<?php
require "db.php";
?>
<form action="login.php" method="POST">

    <p>
        <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Введите почту" value="<?php echo @$data['login'];?>">
    </p>
    <?php
    $data = $_POST;
    if (isset($data['do_login']))
    {
        $errors = array();
        $user = R::findOne('users', "email = ?" , array($data['email']));
        if($user)
        {
            if (password_verify($data['password'], $user->password))
            {
                $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $user;
                echo '<div style = "color:#00ff13;">Вы авторизованы! <br> Можете перейти на <a href="/www/">главную </a>страницу!</div><hr>';
            }
        }else
        {
            $errors[] = "Неверный логин или пароль";
        }
        if(! empty($errors) )
        {
            echo '<div style = "color:red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
        }
    }
    ?>



    <p>
        <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Введите пароль" value="<?php echo @$data['password'];?>">
    </p>
    <a href="recovery.php">Забыли пароль?</a>
    <p>
        <button type="submit" name="do_login">Войти</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: У вас не может вывести "не найден пользователь", потому что такого блока нет в коде

Comment: я имел ввиду (Неверный логин или пароль)

Answer (score 0):

У вас в поле вводится значение с name="login":

```
<input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Введите почту" value="<?php echo @$data['login'];?>">
```

, а из массива $_POST достается и ищется в базе значение email:

```
 $user = R::findOne('users', "email = ?" , array($data['email']));
```

Я так понимаю что из формы значение email вообще не приходит, поэтому в базе ищется пустота

Если дело в этом, то я бы добавил проверку на пустоту переменной $data['email']

Comment: Спасибо,буду пробовать!